# Jquery get value by radio button click

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc

From my below html code ,i want values by click on radio button using jquery.
i already go class="tech" text by using tech :  `$(this).closest('td').siblings('td.tech').text()`

1.Get clicked radion button value,text

2.When i clicked a radio button get its table head (class="factor")

```
  <table id="listTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Skill ID</th>
                    <th>Skill Name</th>
                    <c:forEach items="${skillfactors}" var="skillfact" varStatus="j">
                        <th class="factor">${skillfact.factorName}</th>
                    </c:forEach>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${technologies}" var="tech" varStatus="i">
                    <tr>

                        <td nowrap="nowrap">${tech.id}&nbsp;</td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap" class="tech">${tech.name}&nbsp;</td>


                        <c:forEach items="${skillfactors}" var="skillfact" varStatus="l">
                            <td nowrap="nowrap"><c:forEach items="${ratingList}"
                                    var="ratings" varStatus="k">

                                    <!-- working code -->
                                    <input type="radio" name="${tech.id}+${skillfact.id}"  class="rating"/>${ratings.name}

                        <br>

                                </c:forEach></td>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image]

Already got skillName.Now i want Radio button clicked value & it's table heading

Comment: If you are doing it in the click handler of the radio then `this.value` should give you the value... else try `$(this).closest('td').find('input:checked').val()`

Comment: to get the caption try `var idx = $(this).closest('td').index(); var caption = $('#listTable thead th').eq(idx).text()`

Answer (score 1):

As said in Arun P Johny's comment above:

If you are doing it in the click handler of the radio then `this.value` should give you the value... else try

```
$(this).closest('td').find(':checked').val()
```

To get factorName, if the code for the template can be modified, you could put a data-factorName attribute in the option itself like:

```
<input 
  type="radio" 
  name="${tech.id}+${skillfact.id}" 
  data-factorName="${skillfact.factorName}" 
  class="rating"/>
...
```

and access it like this

```
$(':radio').on('click', function(){
  var skillFactorName = $(this).data('factorName');
});
```

faster and more readable than other solutions imho

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VvX5/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr class="head">
        <td class="tab1">one</td>
        <td class="tab2">two</td>
        <td class="tab3">three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
        <td><input type="radio" name="one"><lable>data one</lable></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="one"><lable>data two</lable></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="one"><lable>data three</lable></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    var table_td_head = $('table').find('tr.head td').length;
    var table_td_data = $('table').find('tr.data td').length;
    $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){        
        $(this).click(function(){
          //alert($(this).next().text());
          var table_inner_td_index = $(this).parent().index();
            alert(table_inner_td_index);
            alert($("table tr.head td:nth-child("+table_inner_td_index+")").attr('class'));
       });
    });
});
```